# how to refresh or revoke OAuth2.0 access/refresh_token, when no refresh token available?

Tags: salesforce, oauth-2.0

I was working in my sandbox environment trying to figure out the Chatter API calls - I had saved my refresh token during my testing but it was lost sometime later.

Now when I try to hit the API I am receiving the following error:

`"expired access/refresh token"`

How do I get around this now?  I do not have a refresh token so i cannot make a request to refresh my token, and i'm not sure how to expire / delete / revoke it via the UI so that I can proceed with my testing.

my cUrl call is as follows:

```
curl
    --form client_id=3MVG92.u...2KycWe
    --form client_secret=668...930
    --form grant_type=password
    --form username=mike....com
    --form password=*#()@*#$@
    --proxy 127.0.0.1:3128 --insecure
  https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
```

Things I have tried:

- Reset my password
- Delete remote access and create a new one with new client_id / secret
- Reset my security token

Does anyone know how to expire the token or get a new refresh token via the API or UI in salesforce?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To revoke access from the UI, click on the following in the menu at the top right of Salesforce: 
Your Name | Setup | My Personal Information | Personal Information and clicking Deny

More info here:
https://na12.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/remoteaccess_about.htm

What scope are you using?  If you specify a scope (like 'api'), you'll need to explicitly request a refresh token by also specifying 'refresh token' in your scope (space delimited).  More info on scopes here:
https://na12.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/remoteaccess_oauth_scopes.htm

[Unlike Google](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2011/10/upcoming-changes-to-oauth-20-endpoint.html), Salesforce will provide the refresh token multiple times, regardless of whether the user has just approved the app or not.

I've been playing around with this using [Google's OAuth playground](https://code.google.com/oauthplayground).  You can click the gear at the top right and specify the values for Salesforce's services.
Authorization endpoint: https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize
Token endpoint: https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
Client ID/secret: from Salesforce's 'consumer' key/secret info in the Remote access Config

You'll need to use 'https://code.google.com/oauthplayground/' as your callback URL in your app configuration.

Comment: unfortunately that didn't solve my problem, i know i can easily enough use other methods of the OAuth API; however, i need to be able to use this for some scripted purposes - which requires i pass in username/password.  Even after clearing out my access from my user record I am receiving the above error.  I will have to keep drilling away at this.  Thank you for what you have provided!

Comment: i'm going to mark this as the answer, since you did answer my question about how to revoke access.  Though I also think the answer to my oauth issues lies somewhere within what you have linked.  I just need to dig deeper and read more.  Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: Thx.  FWIW - Provided salesforce gives you an indefinite refresh token (either through the web-based flow or through the credentials assertion you're demonstrating), I would typically store the refresh token itself rather than the username/password.  Much safer that way :)

Comment: Oh absolutely, this was testing for an API call we needed to make.  I needed to slam bam update a ton of users photos all at once - i know it can be done through the API (or at least i've done file uploads).  I just needed to be able to pop in my user credentials and execute the script :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in your account under:

`My Settings | Select Personal | Advanced User Details | OAuth Connected Apps`

[Exact steps at salesforce can be found here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_request_manage.htm)