# Is there any way to revoke all Google OAuth2 Refresh Tokens for a user without having the latest token?

Tags: google-oauth

If I had saved refresh tokens for my users, I wouldn't be interested in trying to acquire a new one.  I was caught totally off guard by Google only giving their tokens a single hour gestation.  That means refresh tokens are all but required unless you want your users to have to re-log into the site or mobile application once an hour.

So now I have a bunch of users with no refresh tokens.  Google isn't supplying me a new one with `approval_prompt=force` or `prompt=none`, and `access_type=offline`.

I need to force Google to send a refresh token despite the fact that one or more were sent previously.  How does a person revoke refresh tokens without having a token to begin with?

I'd rather not have to ask each user to revoke it manually.  This should be done pragmatically - especially in light of mobile development.

I'd like to focus on a javascript solution if one is available.

I saw a previous posting with the same question, but it is in a completely different context and never received an answer in relation to Google OAuth2.0:
[how to refresh or revoke OAuth2.0 access/refresh_token, when no refresh token available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10627628/how-to-refresh-or-revoke-oauth2-0-access-refresh-token-when-no-refresh-token-av)

Comment: What do you mean by "Google isn't supplying me a new one with approval_prompt=force or prompt=none, and access_type=offline". You certainly should receive one in this case. Can you paste here your complete request URL?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of passing `approval_prompt=force`, instead you need to pass `prompt=consent` and it will make the user consent to Offline Access again - which in turn will generate you a new refresh token.

Answer (score 2):

They say

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#refresh

that a fresh token can be revoked by sending a request containing **either** a refresh token (which you don't have) but also an access token.

> The token can be an access token or a refresh token. If the token is an access token and it has a corresponding refresh token, the refersh token will also be revoked.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor.  That's what the documentation says, but unfortunately that doesn't seem to be what's happening.  I still don't get a refresh token on the next login after I run: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token={users_current_access_token}  The current refresh token doesn't seem to be revoked with that command.  I do use both approval_prompt=force and access_type=offline.

Comment: Sounds like a bug? If the previous token is revoked and you log with access_type=offline, the new token just should be issued, according to the docs. I would contact their support if I were you.

Comment: Good idea.  I'll check the bug tracker to see if anything is amiss.  BTW, the Google forum mentioned that support has been transferred here to Stack Overflow: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/oauth2-dev/cC5B0VIfDf0

Comment: Great, didn't know that. I also wonder what the official response would be.

Comment: Any progress on that? Or a contact from someone from Google?

Answer (score 0):

In 2020, this didn't resolve the problem. I needed to generate a new `refresh_token` in OAuth2 for Google API.

I solved it by doing this:

1. Click on API and Services https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials
2. Enter "OAuth consent screen".
3. Change the name of the app, for example: "My NameApp2".
4. Now again, execute your POST request on your app (`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?...`) and see your new `refresh_token`.